# Shown emojis are different to them chosen, why?

Tags: android, emoji

I just implemented this library in my android app (with your help):
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

It looks like this now:
[image]

As you can see, the smiley I picked from the menu looks different to the one send. Its another theme or someting like that.

Is this controlled by each smartphone itself? How does this work? Does anyone know? How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `EmojiconTextView` from the same library to make sure that emojis are displayed the same way.

Comment: @Smileek: Wow, that was so simple. Please write an answer, so you get the bounty.

Comment: Let's leave it that way as an explanation what's the difference between comment and good answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextView you must be creating in the xml should be `EmojiconTextView` instead of normal `TextView`. Same way make your `EditText` as `EmojiconEditText` so that it can read the emoji as well.

If you want to understand why this is happening, then the answer is, Emojis are nothing but unicodes. Your `TextView`s and `EditText`s needs to be taught how to read them. If you use normal `EditText`, it will read it the Android way, if you use `EmojiconEditText`, it will read it the library way.

Comment: Yes. this should work. This must be marked correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on the OS, (smartphones, computers or any devices). Emojis are just unicode characters which have to be interpreted. And i was was surprised when i managed to compile a c/c++ program with emojis as std output on my Mac (and had a custom terminal prompt with lot of emojis). But obviously i don't think I could compile that on a Linux machine.

You should do something on your TextField so that it will correctly read the emojis, and not with the default behaviour/encoding.

Hope this will help you :

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/index.html